# Check a checkbox on a dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a way to automatically check a checkbox when a selection is made from a dropdown. The HTML code looks something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check1" />Process 1:</td>
        <td>
            <select id="process1" name="process1">
                <option value="null">--Select Process--</option>
                <option value="NameA">NameA</option>
                <option value="NameB">NameB</option>
                <option value="NameC">NameC</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If possible, if the user goes back and selects `--Select Process--`, the checkbox would uncheck

What would the Javascript code look like for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('#process1').change(function() {
        var selected = $('#process1 option:selected');
        if (selected.val() == "null") {
            $('input[name="check1"]').prop('checked', false);
        }
        else {
            $('input[name="check1"]').prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you use this same type of logic to check against values in the database? My dropdown list is populated with Categories from the db, and based off of the value of the category, one or more rows in my grid will have the checkboxes selected.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/edz8B/1/)

JS

```
function setChk(value){
    var chk = document.getElementById('check1');
    chk.checked = (value != 'null');
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1"/>Process 1:</td>
        <td>
            <select id="process1" name="process1" onchange="setChk(this.value);">
                <option value="null">--Select Process--</option>
                <option value="NameA">NameA</option>
                <option value="NameB">NameB</option>
                <option value="NameC">NameC</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery would be easier, but in Javascript, try adding an onchange attribute to the select:

```
onchange="checkValue()"
```

Then in javascript:

```
function checkValue() {
   var e = document.getElementById("process1");
   var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
   if (value == "null") {
      document.getElementById("check1").checked=false;
   } else {
      document.getElementById("check1").checked=true;
   }
}
```

Just add an id to the checkbox id="check1"

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15011401/1292492) answer is really cool!

But if you open that would use jQuery then the code would look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery('#process1').on('change', function() {
        var selectedVal = jQuery(this).find('option:selected').val(),
            checkbox = jQuery('input[name="check1"]');
        if (selectedVal !== 'null') {
            checkbox.attr('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
            checkbox.removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NhGr5/1/)