# Check and uncheck a Checkbox depending on Picklist field values on a form

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, salesforce

I've found the answer to my question if it were dependent on just one value

This was: [Check a checkbox on a dropdown selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011227/check-a-checkbox-on-a-dropdown-selection)

However, the fact that this solution uses 'value' stops it from being ideal for me, as I need the values to be the same as the labels as they're going though to an external database, Salesforce.

This is how far I've got based on examples

**JS**

```
function setChk(value){
    var chk = document.getElementById('00ND0000005VTZq');
    chk.checked = (value != "Parent");
}
```

But I want not equal to Parent, Pupil and Other. Putting an array around it doesn't seem to work.

**Html**

```
<label for="00ND0000005VTZq">Works for Organisation:</label>
<input  id="00ND0000005VTZq" name="00ND0000005VTZq" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<select id="00ND0000005iNnp" name="00ND0000005iNnp" title="General Enquiry - School Role"  onchange="setChk(this.value);">
<option value="Parent" worksfor="n">Parent</option>
<option value="Teacher" worksfor="y">Teacher</option>
<option value="PTA Member" worksfor="y">PTA Member</option>
<option value="School Management Team" worksfor="y">School Management Team</option>
<option value="Governor" worksfor="y">Governor</option>
<option value="Pupil" worksfor="n">Pupil</option>
<option value="Other" worksfor="n">Other</option>
</select>
```

I initally tried setting another variable called 'worksfor' but I am a Javascript novice and couldn't figure out which instance of 'value' I had to change to 'worksfor' in the  two 'SetChk's or if that was the thing to do or if it only works with value...

Comment: I don't get it? You don't want to compare a value, but a label, is that what you're saying ?

Comment: No, I do want to compare values, but I can't set them to anything else than what they are so the javascript I posted from an example doesn't work. That javascript would require that all values that tick the checkbox have to be the same as you can only set one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an if statement:

```
if (value!="Parent"  && value!="Pupil" && value!="Other") 
{
    chk.checked = true;
};
```

The opposite to `AND`(`&&`) is `OR`(`||`)

modify the statement to work with what you want, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's not doing anything though but it must be me doing something wrong. Would it be

`function setChk(value){
    var chk = document.getElementById('00ND0000005VTZq');
    if (value!="Parent"  && value!="Pupil" && value!="Other") 
{
    chk.checked = true;
};
}`

?

Comment: @Beatchef Yes, that is how it should work. I'm sorry it doesn't, I am unsure why. Maybe try to remove the `value= "1"` from your select?